# Infinite update loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a reusable Image Loader component in Vue.js, which should:

1. Manage its own thumbnail data
2. Take `src` from parent as prop
3. Display different thumbnails based on prop, using same instance without being destroyed

So it may take data from two places (own thumbnail state || src prop), and I have a very difficult time wrapping my head around how to manage this. Not too sure if this is the right approach to the problem either.

At this point I am getting an infinite update loop warning in the console.

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

Here is my code. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label class="fileContainer">
      <span class="icon is-large">
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="file" :index="index" @change="updateThumbnail"/>
    </label>

    <object
      :data="pdfURL"
      type="application/pdf"
      :class="{visible: pdfURL != ''}">
    </object>

    <img :src="getSrc()" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["index", "srcProp"],
  data() {
    return {
      imageSrc: '',
      imageDataURI: '',
      pdfURL: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSrc() {
      if (typeof this.srcProp !== "undefined") {
        this.imageSrc = ''
        if (this.srcProp !== '') {
          this.imageSrc = this.srcProp
        } else {
          this.imageSrc = this.imageDataURI
        }
      } else {
        this.imageSrc = this.imageDataURI
      }
      return this.imageSrc
    },
    updateThumbnail(event) {
      this.$emit('change')
      const fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
      const imgFile = event.target.files[0] || event.srcElement.files[0]
      const extension = imgFile.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()
      const isImg = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1

      if (extension === 'pdf') {
        const pdfURL = URL.createObjectURL(imgFile);
        this.pdfURL = pdfURL
        this.height = 200
        return
      } else if (isImg) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.imageDataURI = reader.result
          return
        }
      } else {
        alert("Please submit images or PDFs only.")
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like `getSrc` should be a computed whose expression is `this.srcProp || this.imageDataURI`

Comment: @RoyJ thanks. That doesn't seem to work because with more than one of these image uploaders the next one still has the same `this.imageDataURI`

Comment: Does your code do what it's supposed to? Is your only issue the warning, or is there something else?

Comment: does the parent component that listens to the `change` event change the `index` property of this compoenent?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Let me explain to you what I know.

When `:src="anyFunction()"` is used it re-renders upto infinite time even after it gets the result.

At this point we get same array for infinite times. Try displaying `console.log('this.imgSrc')`, you will get infinite number of array.

Here we cannot use slice or splice to get the first array. I haven't found solution but I managed to keep variables in a src rather than rendering whole function and getting url.

```
<img :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=500x250&markers=color:red%7Clabel:L%7C'+this.leadIpinfo.loc.split(',').slice(0,1)+','+this.Ipinfo.loc.split(',').slice(1,2) alt="loc">
```

Here I have fetched the array and splited and sliced into 2 values.

Hope it could help in some ways.

Comment: You should most likely abstract that into a computed function because that much logic inside a dynamic parameter looks like code smell